# Applying Rcpp on a dataframe

Tags: c++, r, rcpp

I'm new to C++ and exploring faster computation possibilities on R through the Rcpp package. The actual dataframe contains over ~2 million rows, and is quite slow.

## Existing Dataframes

Main Dataframe

```
df<-data.frame(z = c("a","b","c"), a = c(303,403,503), b = c(203,103,803), c = c(903,803,703))
```

Cost Dataframe

```
cost <- data.frame("103" = 4, "203" = 5, "303" = 6, "403" = 7, "503" = 8, "603" = 9, "703" = 10, "803" = 11, "903" = 12)

colnames(cost) <- c("103", "203", "303", "403", "503", "603", "703", "803", "903")
```

### Steps

df contains z which is a categorical variable with levels a, b and c. I had done a merge operation from another dataframe to bring in a,b,c into df with the specific nos.

First step would be to match each row in z with the column names (a,b or c) and create a new column called 'type' and copy the corresponding number.

So the first row would read,

```
df$z[1] = "a"
df$type[1]= 303
```

Now it must match df$type  with column names in another dataframe called 'cost' and create df$cost. The cost dataframe contains column names as numbers e.g. "103", "203" etc.

For our example, df$cost[1] = 6. It matches df$type[1] = 303 with cost$303[1]=6

## Final Dataframe should look like this - Created a sample output

```
df1 <- data.frame(z = c("a","b","c"), type = c("303", "103", "703"), cost = c(6,4,10))
```

Comment: Hello Prasanth, welcome to SO. Could you clarify a few things for us? 1. What exactly are you trying to achieve? I find it hard to understand the intention of the transformation. 2. What have you tried so far? Where is Rcpp failing? 3. What exactly is the reference to shiny apps based on? Your question does not seem to depend on it. Please clarify.

Comment: I have edited the question. Hope it clarifies now. It doesn't specifically relate to shiny and have removed that from the tags.

Comment: From your question, it seems you might be best serverd by learning some `data.table` tricks.  It is unlikely you will beat the performance of `data.table` with simple Rcpp code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A possible solution,  not very elegant but does the job:

```
library(reshape2)

tmp <- cbind(cost,melt(df)) # create a unique data frame

row.idx <- which(tmp$z==tmp$variable) # row index of matching values
col.val <- match(as.character(tmp$value[row.idx]), names(tmp) ) # find corresponding values in the column names
# now put all together
df2 <- data.frame('z'=unique(df$z),
                  'type' = tmp$value[row.idx],
                  'cost' =  as.numeric(tmp[1,col.val]) )
```

the output:

```
> df2 
  z type cost
1 a  303    6
2 b  103    4
3 c  703   10
```

see if it works

Comment: Thanks for this. It would be really helpful if you could share a sample code in C++ using the Rcpp package, as I'm trying to implement this technique for my dataset

Comment: Hello Prasanth, I dare speculate that people are confused because you haven't shown any Rcpp/C code in your question, so far.

Let me ask to the point: the operations that you describe in your "steps" section is what you want translated into Rcpp? What have you tried so far? The fundamentals of Rcpp are described in the ['Advanced R' book by Hadley Wickham](http://adv-r.had.co.nz/Rcpp.html).

Comment: And after thinking about it for a while I want to encourage you to try the code by @efz. You have asked for Rcpp, true. But you also stated that your actual problem is speed. You can have enormous variations in speed depending on how you implement a solution. Once, I reduced a 70 min simulation to 3 seconds and I never used any Rcpp. So, maybe the answer could be of some use to you. You do not have to accept it of it does not solve your problem. I only ask you to keep an open mind.

Comment: A little bird tells me there may even be an entire book on Rcpp...